# viewmodel factory class doesn't work after update lifecycle version

Tags: android

I was using `def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"` ,

`implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")` .

but I had to update version to `def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-alpha03"` to use some features, but `ViewModelProvider.Factory` class doesn't work after I use `def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-alpha03"`.

```
class ViewModelFactory(private val param:String,private val param2: String) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ReviewViewModel::class.java)) {
            ReviewViewModel(param,param2) as T
        }else if(modelClass.isAssignableFrom(FoodViewModel::class.java)){
            FoodViewModel(param,param2) as T
        else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}
```

the error messages are

! `Class 'ViewModelFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T defined in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory`

!   `'create' overrides nothing`

Thanks..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You've written:

```
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
```

But what the error message is saying is that `create` must always have a non-null `ViewModel` type. You need to change your method signature to remove the `?` that indicates nullability on your `<T : ViewModel?>`:

```
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
```

This is specifically called out in the [Lifecycle 2.4 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.4.0):

> *Source-breaking change*: `ViewModelProvider` has been rewritten in Kotlin. `ViewModelProvider.Factory.create` method now longer allows nullable generic.

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed my issue with the help of above two answers, but I am just extending answer that we need to do that is

1. Remove `?` that indicate nullability on your `<T :ViewModel?>`, as below

   ```
   override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {}
   ```
2. Change `ViewModelProvider.Factory` to `ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory()`

Answer (score 3):

that is deprecated right now so you Can use - ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory() - instead of it. and this is the link from the documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders

Comment: Remove the ?, and change ViewModelProvider..Factory by ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory()