# viewmodel factory class doesn't work: 'create' overrides nothing

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel

im new in Kotlin and im trying to build app with 3 functions, one of them is 'Note'

for Note, I've created fragments, database, model, repository, viewmodel but its stuck at view model provider factory

Lifecycle version: 2.2.0

```
`class NoteViewModelProviderFactory(
    val app: Application,
    private val noteRepository: NoteRepository
) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return NoteViewModel(app, noteRepository) as T
    }
}
```

Error: 'create' overrides nothing`

When delete "?" app starts but it redirects to main activity

I was seraching resolutions here: [viewmodel factory class doesn't work after update lifecycle version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69892377/viewmodel-factory-class-doesnt-work-after-update-lifecycle-version) but nth works

Pls help :c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [viewmodel factory class doesn't work after update lifecycle version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69892377/viewmodel-factory-class-doesnt-work-after-update-lifecycle-version)

Comment: Unfortunately not